# Can I use generic 40 pin edp display cable for my laptop screen?

Tags: laptop, display, cable

I own an Acer Nitro 5 AN515-45-R4GR, which I bought on 20th May, 2021, and it is out of warranty. It has a 2560x1440 screen at 165Hz, and it suddenly had horizontal lines on it. I was watching a YouTube video, and the lines developed suddenly across the whole screen. There is no physical damage or pressure of any sort, nothing has been spilled. Since then, I've reset the drivers, booted in safe mode, checked in BIOS, and the lines were there. I plugged in a TV using HDMI, and it was working fine, so it's a hardware issue.

One guy at a local repair shop suggested it could be a cable issue. The problem is, I cannot find the display cable of my laptop anywhere in India, not even the screen, and shipping from abroad costs a ton. Thankfully, I've managed to find a 40 pin edp display cable, and my screen has a 40 pin cable as well. Part number does not match, which is why I wanted to ask can I try and plug that cable to see if it solves the problem?

Comment: Might also be worth just cleaning the current cable and re-seating it into the ribbon cable clip.

Comment: @Baa I've tried that mate, didn't work

Comment: If you can please provide the part number or info on the back of the LCD display we could find the connector type to help find a LCD display cable replacement for you. Hopefully its the cheaper cable as it COULD be the LCD display itself

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the cable I would 100% in your position try the new cable. If you haven't purchased the new cable, I'd try unplugging & re-plugging in the LCD cable at the back of the LCD & on the laptop motherboard by chance it jiggled loose a bit. I would personally try to find the original cable on any website (alibaba or ebay), but sounds like you already tried w/o success. I also in your situation would try a generic one. Here is some resources on the different LCD display connectors:

- https://www.laptopscreen.com/English/section/Articles/1245191276/Screen+connector/
- https://www.vesa.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/DisplayPort-DevCon-Presentation-eDP-Dec-2010-v3.pdf